# How tell current situation? Verb Past Tense or Present Perfect Tense?

Tags: sentence-construction

Friend: Please give me access of your computer.

I did some changes in the system.

What should be my reply to him?

a) I gave you the access, please check?

b) I have given you the access, Please check?

Comment: "Give me access ***to*** your computer."

Comment: What would be my answer to his question?

Comment: In reality, I would likely respond simply with "Done."

Answer (score 1):

Past tense or present perfect are both possible and correct here. You could use present perfect to emphasise the idea that "... and you still have access".  But other than that you could use either.

You don't say "the" access, and these are not questions, so no question mark.

> I've given you access. Please check.

If you were talking to a friend, there would probably be more chat. This short plain speech is more appropriate if you are talking to an engineer.